# How to cope with multiple rejections

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, recruitment, rejection

For the last two weeks, I have been interviewed by many companies but I got negative feedback from all. I'm feeling down. I gave my best, even I cleared written tests and preliminary rounds with no +ve result at the end.

Comment: How many interviews did you do in this period

Comment: Three interviews... :(

Comment: You can keep going by making yourself a "goal" to get rejected some large number of times, say 20 times. Of course don't make this known to anyone and you still do your best, it's just a trick to get yourself to keep going even if it seems difficult. After all each job will have to choose someone, they can't say yes to everyone.

Comment: What was the negative feedback? Was it regarding interview technique or your suitability for the job?

Comment: Actually when job consultant sends me JD, that JD fits to my current role, so I apply for that . But when I go for interview...there is sm other story being asked....

Comment: So after you went to the interview and heard the new story, did you no longer want the job?

Comment: After I insists that I was called for that particular skill...they ask few questions regarding that and seems unconvinced.. though I mention them that I can adapt to that job profile...I am frustrated because of current work environment and looking for change. Getting so many rejections then makes you feel miserable. I am thinking of taking a job cut for the same.

Comment: Why downvote...anything not clarified ?

Comment: How many interviews you said 3 but I think you should make more attempts before you get down. Is your question how to improve or is your question just "help cheer me up". Actually rereading your question I don't see any question

Comment: The headline itself says so....and its not about cheer me up its just that I feel dejected

Comment: Maybe you can apply for a job that you probably don't want. I don't know like something too easy for you but don't let them know. Then try to get an offer. Then reject the offer. This will prove to yourself that you're still good enough to get an offer. Oh, and if that process sounds like a big waste of time, then it probably is and it just means you have to keep searching. 3 non offers doesn't mean anything about your hirability

Comment: Will try this thing...applying for an easy job then get confidence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16152/discussion-between-brandin-and-cbinder).

Comment: Do not be disheartened.  WalMart opened up a new store in my city recently.  They claimed they were more selective in hiring than Harvard is at admitting.  Less than 5% of applicants got a job.  That tells me if you want a WalMart job you need to make over 20 applications.  If you want a better job, you need to apply more.  Regardless you should expect to be turned down 20+ times.

Comment: Learn something from each interview. What questions didn't I answer well? Should I have added more detail to this answer? How could I have demonstrated my expertise more? Did I project any negativity in any of my answers? Do a post-mortem with every interview. Write down your thoughts so you don't forget. Read up on interviewing. Think of each interview as practice and not it's the end of the world if I don't get this job. Your nervousness will be projected and subconsciously cause others to feel less confident in your abilities. Write down every question you remember and prepare an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not everything in life goes the way we want it to, or the way we expect.

When you run into obstacles, you have a couple of choices:

- Keep trying.  There may be an element of chance at work and you may succeed on the next attempt.
- Learn from each attempt.  Thomas Edison tried many different materials when inventing the lightbulb.  This led to the famous saying, ["I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Thomas_Edison)
- Move on / pick a new obstacle.  You won't get to the moon by flapping your arms.  Flapping harder won't help.  Finding new ways to flap (possibly with wings) won't cut it.

In your specific case I'd go for a combination of the first two.

- Keep trying - unless you're applying for basic labor, assume it may take a couple of months to find the right position.  Don't give up easily!
- Learn from each attempt.  Pay attention to what the interviewer says, what their body language is like, their attitude, etc.  With practice you'll know even before the end of the interview whether you'll be offered the job, and why or why not.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: This question is part of this week's [Broken Windows For Review](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2960/broken-windows-for-review-week-4) on meta.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised to see that you are complaining just after 3 interviews. People apply to 50-100 jobs in 2 months, get few interviews, most of which end in rejection. Some of these people finally get a decent or excellent job after 2-3 months, even smart folks with degrees. So, don't think you have seen the worst.
Don't be disheartened and keep trying. More importantly, learn from the mistakes you made in each of these interviews.

Life is not easy or fair. So quit complaining and try to see how you can make things better. The first weakness I see from your question is that you cannot take rejection and failure easily. I won't be surprised if your interviewers saw this too.

If your questions were like the ones given below, it would give a different impression of you:

I got rejected for abc reasons. I don't think I handled xyz question properly. Can you suggest better ways to answer such questions ? Are there any good questions for practising ruby programming, because my performance was not so good in that section.